# How do we compute correlation function in the Schrodinger picture?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

From concreteness' sake consider $\phi^4$ theory with a real scalar (even though the choice of the theory has nothing to do in principle with what I am going to ask).

Consider thefollowing correlation function
$$
<\Omega|T\{\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\}|\Omega>
$$
My question is, do we have to understand the formula above as given in the Heisenberg picture, the Schrodinger picture, or it doesn't matter? What motivates this question is that if we were in the Schrodinger picture i wouldn't know how to take the time ordering of the fields. On the other hand, if it really is meant to be understood in the Heisenberg picture, it is dissatisfying for me not to have a means to compute correlation functions in the Schrodinger picture. So which one is it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. An expression of the form $\langle\psi\vert O\vert\psi\rangle(t)$ looks the same in all pictures, it's not "understood" in any picture. The means to compute correlation functions in QFT is the LSZ formula, which is usually derived in some sort of "interaction picture" which is neither here nor there and possibly doesn't even exist (cf. Haag's theorem), but which *itself* doesn't make any reference to pictures as it contains only picture-invariant objects. So what's the question?

Comment: @ACuriousMind how do you define a time ordered product of fields in the Scrodinger picture?

Comment: Fields are but an infinity of oscillators packaged systematically. For one oscillator, recall, e.g. the first excited state is  
$\psi_1(x,t)=\langle x \mid e^{-3i\omega t/2} a^\dagger \mid 0 \rangle $
, no? So w.f. s are the exact obverse of operators. Proceed to evaluate the bilinear in creation/annihilation operators, inserting complete sets of time-dependent states, if you really feel the urge to relegate time dependence there.